# MySQL Select mulitple Row/Group Multiple/Order

Tags: php, mysql, chat

I'm building a Chat System where User A can talk with User B about Topic X or Y.

My Table looks like following:

```
Message ID | message | sender | receiver | topic
1            Helo      1        2           X
2            Lorem     2        1           X
3            Foo       1        2           Y
4            Bar       2        1           X
5            Test      2        1           Y
6            Hello2    1        3           X
```

So I want to get a List of the 6th last Conversation of User 1 per User and Topic. Currently I got

```
SELECT messageid, sender,topic, receiver AS friend FROM table WHERE sender = 1 || receiver = 1 GROUP BY topic,friend ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

But this doesn't selects the **last** messages. Because afterwards I create a List of those entrys and wan't to show the last conversations on top...

In this Example I need a List like following:

```
 Message ID | sender | topic| friend
 6            1         X      3
 5            2         Y      1
 4            2         X      1
```

With the following select it works!
`select * from (select Message_ID,sender,topic, receiver AS friend from tab where sender = 1 || receiver = 1 
    order by Message_ID desc) temp
    group by topic order by Message_ID desc`

works!

Comment: `ORDER BY MessageID DESC LIMIT 2`?

Comment: you want the 6th or last six conversation messages?

Comment: You use group by but in the code there are not aggegate function .. why you use group by?

Comment: I want the last six conversation.

Comment: @chack : I guess, you want last row of grouping clause. Check it out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf53d/10

Comment: Define 'conversation'

Comment: A conversation is defined by the 2 Users and the topic. Example: I could have unlimited private conversations with you by choosing a different topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess, the issue is first row is selected on `group by` clause.
It can be easily solved by using `order by` clause before grouping them.

```
select * from
(select Message_ID,sender,topic, receiver AS friend from tab
 where sender = 1 || receiver = 1 
order by Message_ID desc) temp
group by friend order by Message_ID desc
```

Kindly verify the answer at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf53d/10

Comment: No sorry, Problem now is that when I got a two Chats (one with User B, one with user C) about Topic X, I got only the last one about Topic X.

Comment: Just added group by friend and it worked! select * from
(select Message_ID,sender,topic, receiver AS friend from tab where sender = 1 || receiver = 1 
order by Message_ID desc) temp
group by topic order by Message_ID desc´`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the id of the last message *id* for a given user:

```
select (case when sender = 1 then receiver else sender end) as other,
       topic, max(messageid)
from messages
where sender = 1 or receiver = 1
group by (case when sender = 1 then receiver else sender end) ;
```

You can then use this to get all the information:

```
select m.*
from messages m join
     (select (case when sender = 1 then receiver else sender end) as other,
             topic, max(messageid) as messageid
      from messages
      where sender = 1 or receiver = 1
      group by (case when sender = 1 then receiver else sender end) 
     ) mm
     on mm.messageid = m.messageid;
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all :( I got a SQL Syntax Error